# How to find file encoding and decode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to understand how to decode a file that Spotify leaves on my system.

The file in question is called `context_player_state_restore` and lives in `/Users/<myuser>/Library/Application Support/Spotify/PersistentCache/`, so obviously the expectation is that its structure (and now encoding likely) can change without warning.

The Spotify app updates that file at regular time intervals with the currently playing song, the current context (e.g. currently playing playlist), and some other useful stuff like the history of played tracks.

I want to parse the information in that file for an app I'm building. (I can use the Spotify API for some of this data, but the local file contains more useful information, is immediate (no delay in API calls), and I can react to any changes on it).

Until recently that file was an UTF-8 JSON file and could be parsed with `JSON.parse(data)`.

Recently however, Spotify has changed that JSON / UTF-8 encoding.

Currently, opening that file with vscode (with UTF-8 encoding) gives back some legible text, indicating that some of the JSON structure has been kept, but also shows a lot of illegible text – the odd question mark symbols `��` and various UTF characters that don't belong e.g. `Ω`.

In short, I'd like to understand:

- whether I can find out what encoding Spotify is now using for this file
- and whether it is possible to decode the file back to JSON (or a similar format) so it can be easily parsed

[Gist link to file dump as seen by vscode](https://gist.github.com/shto/6ceb19b1fd369e91774afaed42735a70)

[Google Drive download of file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RitzsEEAVtfW8nGObMbWOSXEuepazrnZ/view?usp=sharing)

[Gist link to hexdump of file](https://gist.github.com/shto/cabbc1a00f59315ac9c03127f9663cb1) (obtained with `hexdump -C context_player_state_restore > context_player_state_restore.hexdump`)

Comment: Why are the four leading spaces not contained in the hexdump?

Comment: My bad, there are no 4 leading spaces. Must have been a copy-paste mistake on my part.

Comment: @alex I have an answer for you, if you are willing to wait a bit during the "grace period". I can already extract data from the file, but I've not yet got code to convert that data into a JSON structure.

Comment: @Alex Sorry the bounty ends with no acceptable Answer. No time for JSON coding yet (real life issues) but if my answer is useful then ask anything towards writing the code. I can write the code (file bytes reading) if you accept.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question

> what encoding Spotify is now using for this file

I believe it is the encoding used by [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#strings). That page gives the example of the string "testing" encoded as `12 07 [74 65 73 74 69 6e 67]`, and this pattern "0x12 followed by the string length followed by the UTF-8 encoding of the string" appears throughout your `context_player_state_restore` file.

If you know the corresponding `.proto` file, you can decode `context_player_state_restore` with the [`protobufjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs) package.

Comment: You're very close. I think they mixed formats, but the important data (worthy to extract) is in this Protocol Buffer format. What to do if there is no proto file to use as dictionary?

Comment: I don't think Spotify meant this file to be read by third parties, so they may keep their proto file private.

Comment: Yeah I had notes to tell Asker about that part. Like the file could even be hard-coded inside Spotify. This [article](https://blog.conan.io/2019/03/06/Serializing-your-data-with-Protobuf.html) link explains why it's needed to decode.

Answer (score 1):

Spotify may have simply switched encodings, or they may be intentionally [obfuscating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) the data. I'd try reading is as an ISO-8859-1 file, as I've seen these confused with UTF-8 in the wild with some frequency. If that doesn't work, try reading the header bytes and BOM bytes (if present) with a hex editor and see if you can deduce the encoding that way. [This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.hexeditor) is a good hex editor for VSCode.

The first few bytes of a file generally indicate it's encoding. There is are useful tables [here](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) and [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). However, even reading the header **you can never be sure what encoding a file is really using**.

For example, a file with the first three bytes `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF` is *probably* a UTF-8 encoded file. However, it might be an ISO-8859-1 file which happens to start with the characters `ï»¿`. Or it might be a different file type entirely.

The first few bytes may also include [Byte Order Marks (BOM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-byte-order-marks?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried ISO-8859-1, but I get (almost) the same text. I've tried getting the hexdump of the file (see attached in original question), but the file starts immediately with a byte for the first character in the file. I've also used the vscode addon you mentioned, same result.

Is there another way to get the first header bytes that would indicate more about the file?

Comment: I'll look at it tomorrow, those first bytes don't match anything on either list I know of.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I want to parse the information in that file for an app I'm building... 
>
> Is it possible to decode the file back to JSON (or a similar format) so it can be easily parsed."*

The format seems easy enough to reverse-engineer. Just use your Hex editor to notice patterns.

For example, most entries seem to follow this format: 
`[Length in 1 byte]`-->`[Content (by Length)]`-->`[END/Delimiter is sometimes byte 0x12]`

Looking at the bytes provided...

**(1)** Starting bytes... 
The first 17 bytes are `31 36 35 39 33 36 33 38 33 36 31 35 33 23 08 0F 12`
The SIZE here is actually at the ending byte: `0x0F` which is **15**. 
I suspect the (towards) ending byte: `0x23` (which is `#`) is itself a delimiter to mark some ending point. 
By selecting all bytes from file start up to this `#` delimiter, we get `31 36 35 39 33 36 33 38 33 36 31 35 33`

Which makes `1659363836153`, which is itself a [UNIX timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/):

```
GMT: Mon Aug 01 2022 14:23:56 GMT+0000
```

Maybe the file was updated 5 minutes before your Question was posted here? *ie*: `asked Aug 1 at 14:29`.

After the UNIX timestamp there follows the delimiter byte `0x23`, followed by an **unknown** `0x08`, followed by a SIZE byte of `0x0F`.
**(2)** Parsing begins...
The next row (bytes position 16 onwards) has the already described pattern of:

`[Length in 1 byte]`-->`[Content (by Length)]`-->`[END/Delimiter is byte 0x12]`

Entries begin with an `0x0A` or an `0x12` (where `0x12` usually means text entry like "false" or similar).

**(3)** File structure

The file seems to have data in this order:

- Player setup/config
- Playlist Names
- Playlist related images

Then under UTF-8 location: `spotify.player.proto.GlobalNode`

- Playlist track details (*ie:* the album it comes from, related image, etc).

However `GlobalNode` comes after the prevoiusly mentioned !player config" which has this example setup (not all items included):

Where `spotify` is a key and `player` would be a sub-entry (child) in a JSON.

```
spotify -> player   -> proto    -> PlayQueueNode

audio   -> episode  -> speed
        -> automix
        
video   ->
        -> subtitles_cc
        -> subtitles

player  -> banned   -> tracks
                    -> context_tracks
                    -> albums
                    -> artists
```